# Convergent Sequence of Functions and their Images

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n(x)\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that converges pointwise to $f(x)$.

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and define $A_{mn} = \{x \in [a,b] : |f_n(x) - f_{m+n}(x)| \leq \epsilon\}$.

I've been told that $A_{mn}
$ is a closed set because $\{f_n(x)\}$ are continuous and the preimage of a closed set is closed when the function is continuous.

My problem is I can't understand what the image is in this case since the conditions on the preimage depend on two functions, $f_n$ and $f_{n+m}$. I was wondering if anyone could help shed some light on this for me.

Comment: Why do you need to understand the image?

Comment: My end goal is to understand why $A_{mn}$ is closed and I've been told it's because under continuous functions the preimage of a closed set is closed. I don't understand how that fact relates to $A_{mn}$

Comment: You don't need to know anything whatsoever about the image. Here is all you need: $f_n$ and $f_{m+n}$ are continuous. Hence so is $f_n-f_{m+n}$. Then the set $A_{mn}$ is the pre-image of the closed set $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ of the continuous function $f_n-f_{m+n}$, hence closed.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a real blonde moment for me. Thank you so much.